# Lock issues on large recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a database table that I use as a queue system, where separate process that talk to each other create and read entries in the table. For example, when a user initiates a search an entry is created, then another process that runs every second or two will pick up that new entry, update the status and then do a search, updating the entry again when the search is complete. This all seems to work well with thousands of searches per hour.

However, I have a master admin screen that lets me view the status of all of these 'jobs' but it runs very slowly. I basically return all entries in the table for the last hour so I can keep an eye on what's going on. I think that I am running into lock issues of some sort. I only need to read each entry, and don't really care if it the data is a little bit out of date. I just use a standard 'Select * from Table' statement so maybe it is waiting for other locks to expire before returning data as the jobs are constantly updating the data.

Would this be handled better by a certain kind of cursor to return each row one at a time, etc? Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really don't care if the data is a bit out of date... or if you only need the data to be 99.99% accurate, consider using [`WITH (NOLOCK)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WITH (NOLOCK);
```

This will instruct your query to use the `READ UNCOMMITTED ISOLATION LEVEL`, which has the following behavior:

> Specifies that dirty reads are allowed. No shared locks are issued to
>   prevent other transactions from modifying data read by the current
>   transaction, and exclusive locks set by other transactions do not
>   block the current transaction from reading the locked data.

Be aware that [`NOLOCK` may cause some inaccuracies in your data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx), so it probably isn't a good idea to use it throughout the rest of your system.

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. 99.9% accuracy is fine, it is just for a general feel of how everything is running.

Answer (score 2):

You need `FROM yourtable WITH (NOLOCK)` table hint.

You may also want to look at transaction isolation in your update process, if you aren't already

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `NOLOCK` (which can lead to very bad things, such as missed rows or duplicated rows) is to [allow read committed snapshot isolation at the database level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345124.aspx) and then issue your query with:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;
```

Comment: That is probably a little complicated for my needs at the moment, but I will keep that in mind for later on. Thanks for the suggestion.